# Writing To and Reading From JSON File

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I am writing a script to check to see if a json file exists.  If it does, then it uses flask **render_template** function to use the data to load a web page.  If it does not, the script queries the database, puts the data in json format, and then creates and writes to the json file.  Here is some example code.

```
from flask import render_template
import json
import os

title = "Tests"
jsonFile = "tests.json"
if os.path.exists(jsonFile):
    return render_template('tests.html', title=title, data='tests')
else:
    data = '{"tests":[{"id":"1","ip_addy":"IP1","name":"name1"},
                      {"id":"2","ip_addy":"IP2","name":"name2"},
                      {"id":"3","ip_addy":"IP3","name":"name3"}
                     ]}'
    with open(jsonFile, "w+") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
    f.close()
    return render_template('tests.html', title=title, data=data)
```

It writes to the **test.json** file just fine, but when I reload the **tests.html** page after creating **test.json**, the html says there are no records to display.  Did I create the json file incorrectly?

Comment: is close(f) ok? For me python complains but it might be that in python 3.6 close(f) became f.close(). 
Also in your case if the jsonFile exist at beginning of script but is empty it will render with data as 'test'.

Comment: Thank you, Simon.  Actually, I did have f.close() rather than close(f).  The json file is not empty.

Comment: Then if it exist you will render the template within the if statement. and data ='test' in your template.
If you would like to read render with the data in the file you should try to read the content of the file before rendering passing it with the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

As @Simon Johansson mentions, it looks like the issue is that you are not reading the contents of the file.  Making just that change seems to work for me.

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    title = "Tests"
    jsonFile = "tests.json"
    if os.path.exists(jsonFile):
        file_data = ""
        try:
            with open(jsonFile) as f:
                file_data = f.read()
        except:
            file_data = "could not read file"
        return render_template('tests.html', title=title, data=file_data)
    else:
        data = {"tests":[{"id":"1","ip_addy":"IP1","name":"name1"},
                          {"id":"2","ip_addy":"IP2","name":"name2"},
                          {"id":"3","ip_addy":"IP3","name":"name3"}
                         ]}
        with open(jsonFile, "w+") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        f.close()
        return render_template('tests.html', title=title, data=data)
```

I tried modifying the file data once written and the changed data does show up correctly, indicating that the data is read from the file ok if present.

I used a simple templates\tests.html

```
<html><head><title>{{title}}</title></head>
<body>Data:<br>{{data}}</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did this along with replacing the file_data = f.read with file_data = json.load(f).  It then worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution to the problem, thanks to Simon and J. Fay.  The data must be written and read as json.

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    title = "Tests"
    jsonFile = "tests.json"
    if os.path.exists(jsonFile):
        file_data = ""
        try:
            with open(jsonFile) as f:
                file_data = json.load(f)
            f.close()
        except:
            file_data = "could not read file"
        return render_template('tests.html', title=title, data=file_data)
    else:
        data = {"tests":[{"id":"1","ip_addy":"IP1","name":"name1"},
                         {"id":"2","ip_addy":"IP2","name":"name2"},
                         {"id":"3","ip_addy":"IP3","name":"name3"}
                         ]}
        with open(jsonFile, "w+") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        f.close()
        return render_template('tests.html', title=title, data=data)
```